# Error: 404 Not Found. File doesnt exist

Tags: python, веб-программирование

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте, при запуске программы появилась проблема. Программа говорит, что файла не существует, хотя он есть.
Это код файла Python

```
import eel

eel.init("web")

eel.start("Neyral.html" , size = (700 , 700))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Это код файла на html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8" >

    <title>Photomaker</title>

    <script src="eel.js"></script>

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/gallery.png">

</head>

<body>

    <h1>Hello, world</h1>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ну значит этот файл не находится в директории со скриптом

Comment: я верю программе, а не программисту. Кто сказал, что файл есть именно там, где его пытается открыть программа? Программист вообще знает, в каком месте ищется этот файл?

Comment: @Эникейщик Целая философия. Я программе верю больше, чем человеку. Мое почтение.

Comment: Не думал django начать изучать?

Comment: @СергейШашко Т.е. вы склоняетесь к тому, что программа обманывает? Файл есть, а она пишет, что нет?

Comment: Я бы проверил написание букв - вдруг где-то русская закралась вместо английской в названии файла, например. Но не уверен.

Comment: @andreymal Так `eel.init("web")` вроде и говорит, что файл `Neyral.html` надо искать в каталоге `web`, где он и находится?

Comment: @CrazyElf ой да

Comment: @Эникейщик Человек говорит что есть файл(а может он врет, но давайте поверим), программа говорит что нет файла(это аксиома). И оба правы.  В чем ошибка человека? Человек не сделал все возможно чтобы программа увидела файл.